# ESP-CoAP server calls resource handler without receiving packages

Tags: c++, esp8266, coap

I Implemented a coap server :

```
#include <coap_server.h>
coapServer coap;
void getListOfWiFi(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port, int obs) //id = 0 GET
{
  Serial.println("hello");
    int numberOfNetworks = WiFi.scanNetworks();

    String WifiList = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNetworks - 1; i++)
    {
        WifiList += WiFi.SSID(i) + "####";
    }
    WifiList += WiFi.SSID(numberOfNetworks - 1);
    char *temp = new char[WifiList.length() + 1];
    WifiList.toCharArray(temp, WifiList.length() + 1);

    coap.sendResponse(ip, port, temp);
    Serial.println("goodbye");
}
void setup()
{
       coap.server(getListOfWiFi, "wifilist");
       coap.start(5683);
}
void loop()
{
     coap.loop();
}
```

When start the esp, the output of serial monitor is :

```
hello
goodbye
hello
goodbye
hello
goodbye
hello
goodbye
hello
goodbye
hello
goodbye
```

And it keeps printing this without any receiving packets or requests...
Why this happens ?
Thanks.

I'm using this coap library : 
https://github.com/automote/ESP-CoAP on esp8266

The output of ip and port is :

```
(IP unset)
port : 
0
```

Comment: Please add information on which CoAP library you are using (link); I've found different coap_server.h that could all be used with ESP8266 and and differ subtly.

Also, printing the IP and port passed in would help in finding the cause of this.

Comment: @chrysn thanks for your reply. I've edit the post.

Comment: @chrysn the output of ip and port is : (IP unset)
port : 
0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this particular CoAP library is internally [regularly polling](https://github.com/automote/ESP-CoAP/blob/1b8802f0d27c8ae7286200534743810b562a256b/coap_server.cpp#L375) the first registered resource for changes with the last received CoAP messate, whenever any package is received, possibly to detect whether an observation is to be sent off.

You may want to take that up with the library's authors, when this is called it looks like a bug in the library.

Comment: thanks for your reply, which other library do you recommend to use ?

Comment: In embedded systems, I've had good experience with the Gcoap library (but that's probably not applicable here as it's built into the RIOT embedded operating system) and libcoap.